# How can we map the user's logon and logoff events

Tags: security, active-directory, event-log

I have some knowledge about the events 4624(logon) and 4634(logoff). As microsoft's document suggests, we can correlate these events with the logonid.

```
  Here my question is, is there any other efficient way to do this?

  Because my need would be, I have to read events for last 30 days, and correlate logon and logonoff events to find the logon duration.
```

As per the document, logonid is unique between reboots on the same computer. so in that period(last 30 days) there may be the possibility of computer rebooted several times. so i suspect,there may be the possibility of duplication in logonid while we analyze the events for last 30 days.

Comment: Not every logon will have an associated logoff, eg when a machine is rebooted without logoff or when a laptop user simply unplugs and goes home.

Comment: we can track user's logon activity by mapping logon and logoff events with user's **Logon ID** which is unique between user's logon and logoff events.

see the following articles 

http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/10/tracking-user-logon-activity-using.html

http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/10/logon-and-logoff-events-in-active.html

http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/10/enable-active-directory-logonlogoff.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track logon and logoff events I would suggest to use logon and logoff scripts that write this information into a database. Using such an approach you don't need to parse eventlogs (on all servers).

Comment: got solution from http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/10/tracking-user-logon-activity-using.html